# error subquery return more than 1 when doing multiple select

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

I want to do a multiple select in one query with different conditions. but somehow i'm stuck in this problem. any idea?

```
SELECT
    (select io_link_event_names.name from doors left join controller_devices on doors.iid = controller_devices.iid left join events on controller_devices.mac = events.mac left join io_link_event_names on events.iolinkerid = io_link_event_names.extra where events.iolinkerid = "9000;1") AS forced,
    (select doors.name FROM doors) AS doorname
```

ERROR #1242 - Subquery returns more than 1 row

Comment: The error message says it all. The question is rather: what are you trying to do?

Comment: That's weird. The query that you show look ok and should not RAISE error `Subquery returns more than 1 row`. Is that actually your running query?

Comment: i'm trying to multiple select in 1 query different WHERE condition. after googling i got those answer but error

Comment: @lalalala what do you mean by `different conditions`

Comment: example like this
select
(select name from doors where name="door1") as door1,
(select name from doors where name="door2") as door2

Comment: where is `"door1"` and `"door2"` coming from? check my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

consider this

```
SELECT d.[forced], doors.name as doorname
from doors
left join (
select  controller_devices.iid, io_link_event_names.name as [forced]
from events
inner join controller_devices on controller_devices.mac = events.mac 
inner join io_link_event_names on events.iolinkerid = io_link_event_names.extra 
where events.iolinkerid = "9000;1"
) as d on d.iid = doors.iid
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have more than 1 row in table doors, you get this error. If you want too see door name relevant to event selected in first query, use

```
select io_link_event_names.name,
       doors.name doorname
  from doors
  left join controller_devices
    on doors.iid = controller_devices.iid
  left join events
    on controller_devices.mac = events.mac
  left join io_link_event_names
    on events.iolinkerid = io_link_event_names.extra
where events.iolinkerid = "9000;1"
```

Comment: i already tried that. but i want different where condition and give alias in each select